# Convergence of $\sum \sin(an)z^n$ when $|z| = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a>0$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$ (to avoid the trivial case).

$\sum \sin(an)z^n$ has radius of convergence $r=1$ , because $$|\sin(an)z^n| \leq |z^n|$$
So if $|z| < 1$ the series converges absolutely by the comparison test.

If $z = 1$, then the series does not converge because $\sin(an)$ does not approach $0$ when $n \to \infty$.
**How can I analyse the case $|z| = 1, z \neq 1$?**

Comment: We still have $\lvert \sin (an)z^n\rvert = \lvert \sin (an)\rvert$ then.

Comment: @Daniel This seems reasonable, but I'm afraid to use it because there are examples when a series converges for $|z| = 1, z \neq 1$, for example $\sum \frac{z^n}{n}$. Using your argument here would lead to a wrong conclusion...

Comment: But $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, whereas, as you wrote, $\sin (an) \not\to 0$ if $a$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} \sin(an) z^n = \text{Im}\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{ian}z^n = \text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{ia} z}\right) $$
that holds as a true equality if $\|e^{ia} z\|=\|z\|<1$. In the special case $\|z\|=1$, or $z=e^{i\theta}$, we have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sin(an)z^n = \text{Im}\sum_{n=0}^{N}e^{in(\theta+a)}$$
but the terms of the last sum are not $o(1)$ as $n\to +\infty$, hence $\|z\|<1$ is both a sufficient and necessary condition for convergence.